Strapi application won't start/connect with digital ocean managed database certificate
I'm trying to deploy a Strapi application that connects to a Digital Ocean managed PostgreSQL database, but I'm encountering an SSL certificate error. When I attempt to start the Strapi server in production, I get the following error:
[2024-07-22 16:30:50.780] error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1659:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1070:8)
    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:856:12)

My database.ts configuration file looks like this:
export default ({ env }) => ({
    connection: {
        client: 'postgres',
        connection: {
            host: env('DATABASE_HOST'),
            port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT'),
            database: env('DATABASE_NAME'),
            user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
            password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
            ssl: {
                ca: env('DATABASE_CA')
            },
        },
        debug: false,
    },
});

I've set all the necessary environment variables, including DATABASE_CA with the certificate provided by Digital Ocean, but I'm still getting this error.
Questions:
How can I properly configure Strapi to connect to a Digital Ocean managed PostgreSQL database with SSL?
Is there a specific way to format or provide the CA certificate for Strapi to recognize it correctly?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

There's a workaround using an ENV var:
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Not recommended for production applications.
